# html table to excel with PHP

Tags: php, export-to-excel

I have looked for answer to other similar questions but couldn't see useful..

I have an html table generated with php from mysql db. 
I use this fragment in my php file to save as excel

```
$file="program.xls";
header('Content-Type: text/html');
$table = $_POST['tablehidden'];//i get this from another php file.It is HTML table
header("Content-type: application/x-msexcel"); //tried adding  charset='utf-8' into header
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
echo $table;
```

1. Till this time everything is ok. But when I save this i get character problem and tried to add  *charset='utf-8'* into my header, I don't know but It does not work.
2. I have my table with style in HTML but when it comes to excel it lost the style which is implemented in css.

How can I solve the charset and styling problems? I have looked at phpexcel but couldn't see a method to include a table directly.

Answer (score 6):

I personally would use a PHP Excel generating class to make the Excel file.  You can find a good one called PHPExcel here: http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thank you for your reply Greco, however there is no method to include a table directly to the phpexcel. It implements cells one-by-one.

Comment: thats kind of what I meant.  Take your data and re-write it to the Excel table as you want it. You will have most control that way

Comment: @gencay - Not just one by one, there is also the fromArray() method, but there is (as yet) no direct method of taking an HTML table (or any block of HTML) and storing it in an Excel worksheet using PHP. However, if you modify the PHP that generates your table, you could get it to output HTML or Excel based on a flag or setting you pass to it.